# How do I build a personal project big enough to learn from automated testing it?

Tags: bdd, tdd

It doesn't come to me, in my head, how I should build a project big enough, like abig software, so I can test it.
I've been reading about testing and I wanna to learn it from zero.
The language that I know is Java. So I wanna know a to-do list to become a professional tester. 
Thanks for everything.

EDIT: My idea is to become a tester, so I need somewhere to start.

Comment: I am reading one blogs from long time. I have found this link for you. Please refer : http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/basic-skills-that-every-tester-fresher-should-have/

Comment: You tagged this BDD and TDD, do you mean how to become good in practising those techniques? Or is your question just very broad?

Comment: The system didn't allow me to put the "automated test" idea. Because of the points.

Comment: `Softwaretestinghelp.com, guru99.com, toolsqa.com`- these sites have demo projects on which you can start testing. These sites also contains good content for tutorial purpose. You can start from there instead of making a whole new big project.

Answer (score 3):

To learn TDD I suggest doing a kata everyday. Start with the [String Calculator Kata](http://osherove.com/tdd-kata-1/) and do it test-driven.

The [coding dook handbook](https://leanpub.com/codingdojohandbook) has loads more example kata's to practise and learn the following skills:

- test design
- refactoring safely
- naming tests
- driving code with tests
- designing clean code

Also read [Test Driven Development: By Example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321146530)

Answer (score 2):

Need to do following:

1. Learn Phases of software development
2. Need to learn why testing is necessary
3. Need to think logically where ans what functionality of an software should have and is software fullfilled the requirement.
4. Learn types od testing
5. Should have good communication and written skills
6. Test an application as End user

Answer (score 2):

@Frank I think for most successful new testers the testing mindset usually precedes a lot of the technical skill depth. When I talk to people starting their testing careers one of my go-to speeches can be summarized as "The only difference between complaining or discussing an application vs testing it is how clearly and thoroughly you document the actual outcome and expected outcome of problems as you encounter them". Many people are able to navigate around applications and look for problems but testing is really about turning these findings into actionable tasks for your development team and that's where effective communication is so critical.

A rampup for many brand new testers will look like this...

1) When the application doesn't do what you expected, practice both speaking and writing what you did, what you expected the application to do, and what it actually did. If you have a friend who wouldn't mind reading your results, see what parts are or aren't understandable to them and focus on improving areas of misunderstanding in the future.

2) As you get more comfortable communicating your findings and your understanding of the application grows, you can communicate even more effectively if you're able to expand or refine your vocabulary. Much of this (ex: development,  UX, design terms) will be common vocabulary for most software shops but some might be specific to the application you're testing. Pay attention to how your peers talk about the application under test and try to be clear and consistent with their standard terminology.

3) Look for ways your can include even more information about your testing results. This may be the use of screenshots, video, application logs, information from Dev Tools or other ways to see a little under the hood. This will become especially important as the complexity of your testing targets and their business requirements grow.

4) Figure out how to test more/faster in the specific situation you find yourself in. Usually this will eventually involve channeling your new-found ability to understand and describe the application and turn it into test automation or scripts that reflect this understanding.

Answer (score 2):

These are my recommendation to be a QA/ Testing

- Learn about the concepts of Testing. Try to understand why using examples in daily life.
- Read about QA & Testing. There are a lot information in Internet, I've seen videos in Youtube or Udemy.
- In your testing, think as common user (End user).
- Always learn something new by example, automation testing.

You can "apply" in some crowd-sourced testing.

- [uTest](http://www.utest.com). It has a lot information about how become a tester and tips.
- [TestIO](https://test.io/)
- [UserTesting](https://www.usertesting.com/)
- [Uxline](http://www.uxline.com/). The website is in Spanish.

Answer (score 1):

To become a professional tester you have to keep a note on the below:

Should be

1. Passionate about Testing.
2. Attitude to break the code.
3. Analytical and Logical skills.
4. Think like an End user while Testing.
5. Good Communication skills.

Always keep you updated with the latest trends in Testing.

Comment: I think we should keeps attitude to find error not to break the code.

Comment: I greatly disagree with "Attitude to break the code" you should have a "Attitude to prevent issues" and to build the best system. Also see the Agile Testing Manifesto: http://www.luxoft-training.com/news/the-agile-testing-manifesto/

Comment: I definitely get paid to figure out how I can break applications in many situations (it's my favorite puzzle!)... but the other half of that is being mindful of the tone of my results, not gloating over or belittling the developer, and making it clear we're all trying to build great software together.

Comment: I guess it is common for testers to be paid for breaking applications, as most managers think this is what testers do. I got pretty good in breaking the system, I can flood a development team with defects users might never hit.This might result in grinding a halt of new development or overload in triage. Great software is software that solves challenges users have, not weird corners cases testers find if they focus on breaking the system. Now maybe breaking the system means something different to you, you might always keep the end-user in mind, but I think it is a mindset we should let go.

Comment: I meant break the code to find issues here. Not to pour unwanted/un related bugs. I am not a fan of it.

Comment: This has also changed over the past 10 years.  10 years ago my motivation (and success) as a quality engineer was in breaking stuff.  The industry has changed since then mostly due to the rise of automation programming.  Now the motivation for a quality engineer needs to be more 'i like to write automated edge case test cases to make sure the application works as intended'.